# why does Os.environ.keys() and Os.environ.items() return the semantically same data?

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables

running Ipython3 using Python3.10 on Ubuntu 22.10

```
a=Os.environ.keys()
b=Os.environ.items()
```

I expect **a** to be a **list** of environmental variable keys/names
such as :

```
['SHELL','SESSION_MANAGER',......]
```

but instead I got:

```
KeysView(environ({'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local....}))
```

and **b** which I expected to return to me tuples of key value pair I got this:

```
ItemsView(environ({'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'SESSION_MANAGER': 'local
```

which to me seems like the same data wrapped in something else. Technically nothing wrong with these two but it seems to me it defeats the purpose if you gave someone a 10$ bill to get a loaf of bread but they just wrap the dollar note in an envelope marked **loaf of bread**

what is it that I am ignorant of here?

Comment: A better analogy is that they wrap the dollar note around a promise to give you the bread when you ask for it. `keys` and `items` return iterators, not values; the values stay where they are until you actually start iterating (at which point you only get what you asked for).

Answer (score 1):

Behavior you observed is not limited to `os.environ` but apply to `dict`s in general. You got a [*view*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) which does observe alterations made to `dict`, consider following simple example

```
d = {"x":10,"y":100}
d_keys = d.keys()
d_list = list(d.keys())
d.update({"z":1000})
print(d_keys)  # dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'z'])
print(d_list)  # ['x', 'y']
```